# Pandas Split DataFrame

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, split

I have a df that currently has 4 columns. The first column is a combination of 3 items delimited by _. For example: `44_title_iphone6_32GB` What I want is `44` `title` `iphone6_32gb` in their own new columns. However, I can't do a simple df.split on _ because then it will separate the iphone6 and 32gb into two. How can I accomplish this? The other issue is that the last of the 3 items isn't always consistent in length, eg. `44_title_iphone5_32gb_white` So regardless I still want number,title,description in each new column.

Help?

Comment: usual rules: 1) raw data, 2) code, 3) desired output, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`split` accepts an `n` parameter for the number of splits:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"stuff": ["44_title_iphone6_32GB", "44_title_iphone5_32gb_white"]})
>>> df
                         stuff
0        44_title_iphone6_32GB
1  44_title_iphone5_32gb_white
>>> df["stuff"].str.split("_", 2)
0          [44, title, iphone6_32GB]
1    [44, title, iphone5_32gb_white]
Name: stuff, dtype: object
```

And then if we `.apply(pd.Series)`, we can promote these to columns:

```
>>> df["stuff"].str.split("_", 2).apply(pd.Series)
    0      1                   2
0  44  title        iphone6_32GB
1  44  title  iphone5_32gb_white
```

UPDATE:

Note that these days you can use `expand=True` instead of `apply(pd.Series)`:

```
>>> df["stuff"].str.split("_", 2, expand=True)
    0      1                   2
0  44  title        iphone6_32GB
1  44  title  iphone5_32gb_white
```

Comment: How can I then change the column names of 0,1,2? I tried this and it's not working? `df = df.rename(columns={"0":"new_name"}, inplace = True)`

Comment: Also, new example. What if the those 3 elements aren't ordered like above? How would I able to do that? For ex:

`44_title_iphone6_32GB'
`iphone6_32GB_33_title`
`title_ipad_24`

@DSM

Comment: @user3508494: the default columns are *numbers*, not strings.  Rename them that way.  Alternatively, you could always assign: `df.columns = ['a','b','c']`.